# tableview cell with two Identifier. for odd one cell and for even another cell in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image]

I want to load Identifier according to odd and even `indexPath`.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    if indexPath.row % 2 == 0{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! categoryTVC
         return cell
    }else{
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellOdd", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! categoryTVC
        return cell
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.categoryDetailArray?.count ?? 00
}
```

this work but there is one problem with this ..its generate one extra cell each time.

Comment: remove this `forIndexPath: indexPath` from both

Comment: doesnt work..still one extra cell. @AnuradhS

Comment: can you shw the screen shot

Comment: Can you show some more code?

Comment: your `numberOfRowsInSection:` method must be returning an incorrect amount of rows

Comment: are u using same `customtableviewCell class` for both `categoryTVC`. your have to use two `customcellclasses` for two cells ,and show us other tableview delegate methods.

Comment: what number you return in `numberOfRowsInSection:`?

Comment: i just upload my code.numberofrowinsection is 25 . @TonyHan

Comment: I use your code, but it works well.It returns 25 cells, 13 cells and 12 oddCells.

Comment: If you have equal number of even and odd cells then `numberOfRowsInSection` should not return odd number!!

Comment: @PrashantGhimire Remember `indexPath.row` starts at 0.

Comment: bt array count give count from 1..25 right. thank you all of you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. But you should remember that if you want equal number of odd and even cells then you should have even number of cells.
So you have to supply either 24 or 26 (an even number of rows) not 25(odd number of rows) in numberOfRowsInSection method.